# Postgresql infinitive loop

Tags: postgresql

I am new to database but I want to create trigger to stop updating when is lower than 0.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buyArticle()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
  $$
  DECLARE
  print record;
  calcquantity integer;


  begin
    SELECT w.iddrug, w.quantity, w.iddrugstore FROM warehouse w 
    INNER JOIN drugstore d on w.iddrugstore = d.iddrugstore WHERE w.iddrug= new.iddrug and 
    w.iddrugstore =new.iddrugstore
    into print;
    calcquantity :=print.quantity-new.quantity;
    if   calcquantity > 0 THEN
            update warehouse set quantity=quantity-new.quantity where iddrug=new.iddrug AND 
     iddrugstore=new.iddrugstore;
        end if;
    RETURN NEW;

end; 
$$

CREATE TRIGGER triggerBuyArticle
BEFORE  UPDATE
ON warehouse
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buyArticle()
```

query is `update warehouseset quantity=2 where iddrug=1 AND iddrugstore=2;`

When I run this query I get an infinite loop and this ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded, the problem is in the if but I do not know why?

Comment: I don't think you *need* a loop. (or a function)

Comment: Do I have a loop? When I start the update, I get ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded HINT: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate. CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT w.iddrug, w.quantity, w.iddrugstore FROM warehouse w INNER JOIN drugstore d on w.iddrugstore = d.iddrugstore WHERE w.iddrug= new.iddrug and w.iddrugstore =new.iddrugstore" PL/pgSQL function buyArticle() line 6 at SQL statement

Comment: Your trigger should execute before update but it does an UPDATE itself, so it is a recursive call still the stack overflows.

Comment: What do you want me to do?

Comment: I Misread. You don't need an `IF`. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be reduced to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buyArticle()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
  $$
  DECLARE

  calcquantity integer;


  begin
    
    calcquantity := old.quantity - new.quantity;
    if   calcquantity > 0 THEN
           new.quantity = old.quantity - new.quantity;
        end if;
    RETURN NEW;

end; 
$$

CREATE TRIGGER triggerBuyArticle
BEFORE  UPDATE
ON warehouse
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buyArticle()
```

It would help if you would indicate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to do something when a customer buys an item and there are only 10 left in stock, but they want to buy 11. The trigger should not allow an update.

Comment: That is doable, just `RETURN NULL` to stop the trigger action when the new quantity goes negative. Do you really want to do that or do want to sell the 10 and back order the 1? Also do you want to do this on the `warehouse` table or on the orders table?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are performing an update in a BEFORE UPDATE trigger. Therefore, every time your trigger is called, it causes another trigger call, until the stack overflows.

If you want to change the values being put into the row as a result of the update, instead of doing an update in the trigger, return a row which contains the actual values you want to show up in the update instead of returning NEW unmodified. For example, in place of your update statement do:
`NEW.quantity := quantity - NEW.quantity; RETURN NEW;`